# Mysql: how to return value or empty string from column ids in table (multi table)

Tags: mysql

I'M trying to extract all information into my table, but I need to change id, when available, to the name into another table.

I have 1 table like that:

```
|------------------------------|
|-id-|-systems-|-remote-|-deco-|
|  1 |   NULL  |   3    |      |
|  2 |    21   |  NULL  |   2  |
|-------------------------------
```

each column like "systems" / "remote" / "deco" refer to an id into another table

I know how to use INNER JOIN. But if I use that, I got an empty result because the value need to be appears into the others tables.

ex.:

```
 SELECT qd.id,s.name as systems,r.name as remote, d.name as deco
 FROM `quote_data` qd 
 INNER JOIN systems s ON qd.systems=s.id
 INNER JOIN remote r ON qd.remote=r.id
 INNER JOIN deco d ON qd.deco=d.id
```

I got empty result.

In the best words, I need to do something like:

```
|------------------------------|
|-id-|-systems-|-remote-|-deco-|
|  1 |         |   R42  |      |
|  2 |   GTV   |        | B21  |
|-------------------------------
```

Also, I use innoDB table

Any Idea how to fix that?

Comment: have you tried LEFT JOIN? Replace all `INNER` with `LEFT` I believe that is the result you want.

Comment: rho... seriously... yeah its good. thanks!